# Remove text from dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a site which for some reason places the text I: at the start of each of the search results in the dropdown menu. It's a feature of the plugin/theme which apparently can't be adjusted manually. So I want to use javascript to remove this text. Is it possible to do this with dynamic text that is generated, such as with search results? I've seen examples of removing text with javascript but in those cases it was for static content and not dynamic...

Comment: which plugin/theme?

Comment: it's Geo Directory

Comment: Can you share a bit more info about what you mean? I use geodirectory a lot and have never encountered this?

Comment: Sure, here's a screenshot. I asked the support team about it and they told me it's a feature that cannot be changed. https://paste.pics/FKEGW